# Estrutura Package IntelliJ

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Sou novo com o Intellij, ainda estou me habituando, no entanto, gostaria de saber se tem como mudar essa estrutura de exibição dos arquivos no package. Segue a estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria deixar que as classes viessem antes das subpastas, algo parecido com isso:

```
br.com.loja
  LojaAppApplication
  LojaAppApplication
  Controller (pasta)
    Arquivos de Controller
    ....
  Models (pasta)
    Arquivos de Models
    ....
```

Não sei se é possível, mas já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Não há essa opção no IntelliJ.

As únicas opções possíveis são:

- exibir as pastas acima dos arquivos (conforme ilustrado no print) ou;
- exibir o conteúdo em ordem alfabética (misturando arquivos e pastas).

Fonte: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html

Comment: Aaah, blz. Obrigado. Com tempo eu me acostumo então.